# Is this consistent behavior between "select" and "autocomplete" options of Tabulator?

Tags: tabulator

to replace raw values I use "lookup" feature of [Tabulator](http://tabulator.info).

But "select" and "autocomplete" behaves differently

```
var country_list = {
  1: "Germany",
  2: "Ukraine",
  3: "Canada",
};

//Build Tabulator
var table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
    height:"311px",
    data: tabledata,
    columns:[
        {title:"ID", field:"id", width:40 },
        {title:"Country", field:"country_id", width:130, 
          editor:"select",
          editorParams:{values: country_list, }, 
          formatter       : "lookup", 
          formatterParams : country_list,
        },
        {title:"Country2", field:"country_id", width:130, 
          editor:"autocomplete",
          editorParams:{values: country_list, }, 
          formatter       : "lookup", 
          formatterParams : country_list,
        },
    ],
});
```

Try to edit `Country` and `Country2` fields:
[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/KES777/geaLr6pz/3/)

"select" displays label, but "autocomplete" displays raw value.

Is this behavior consistent?
If yes, how to force Tabulator to hide raw value?

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug, a fi has been pushed to the 4.2 branch which should be released shortly